# How to list and use packages in Yarn 2?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

Since I'm a beginner with Yarn, therefore I have followed the current Yarn tutorial, and it describes Yarn 2. So I have installed Yarn 2. `yarn --version` command gives `2.0.0-rc.34`.

But Yarn 2 seems to lack a command to show the list of the packages installed locally. I know that Yarn 1 has the `list` command, but I cannot find any similar command in Yarn 2.

I use Yarn 2 for a new empty project, I have added webpack with the command `yarn add -D webpack webpack-cli`. Yarn 2 seems to store packages completely differently -- it hadn't created `node_modules` directory, it seems to use the `.yarn` directory for the packages. So `npm list` shows nothing.

Furthermore when I try `npx webpack --help`, npm doesn't find webpack, and proposes to install it with `yarn add -D`, though I had done that already.

So how to see a list of all installed packages, and how to make npm see them with Yarn 2?

My system is Linux Mint 19.3, Node.js version is 12.18.0, npm version is 6.14.4. Node.js was installed from the deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x repository.

Comment: It's important to realize that `npm` and `yarn` are both node-package managers. So what you have installed by either can't be seen by the other.

Comment: @MwamiTovi, when I install packages with Yarn 1, they appear in `node_modules`, so npm **perfectly** sees them. They are interchangeable.

But this is not the case with Yarn 2.

And this doesn't clear the question, how to do this with Yarn 2 itself.

Answer (score 11):

Not a timely response, but it may still be of use.  With Yarn 2.4.0, running `yarn info --recursive --dependents` in the root of your repo will list them. There are other options, check out [yarn info](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/info)

Answer (score 0):

Yarn 2 really has no `list` command yet, but there is a request to add it (https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/720).

Yarn 2 really stores the packages differently, and in contrast to Yarn 1 is not compatible with `npm`.

To launch webpack with Yarn 2, one can use `yarn run webpack` or even `yarn webpack`.

Comment: And now there's `yarn info --name-only`.